# How to count in a Pivot Table?

Tags: vba, excel, count, pivot-table

I wrote VBA coding for "Pog Group" and "Item#" in the row.

I want to count how many times the Item# repeats in each Pog Group in this Pivot table. I can sum but I do not know how to count them.

In the picture I showed below coding can realize the effect on the left Pivot Table, but I want to realize the effect on the right.

```vb
Sub creatpivottable2()

Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Worksheets("SKU & POG DataResource").Select

Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Cells(1,  1).CurrentRegion)
Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache,    TableDestination:=Range("E4"))

With PT
    .PivotFields("POG Group").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("Item #").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("Trait #").Orientation = xlDataField
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Please see the picture I uploaded which shows the effect I realized right now and the effect I want to show. the problem is how to use count in Pivotfields

Comment: hmm.. try macro recording ? its good source of reference

Answer (score 0):

use this snippet:

```
With PT
    .PivotFields("POG Group").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("Item #").Orientation = xlRowField
    With .PivotFields("Trait #")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlCount
    End With
End With
```